# Appending lists to a new list in python as objects

Tags: python, mongodb, list, iterable

Querying a mongoengine db as lists I would like to append them to a new list that iterable. My current code:

```
data=[]
other_doc = Document.objects(bank="boe_dd4a95f6ec1c41ba47239fe6fd688b8cc1232c3d25a68b76836172d99164cb82")
data.append(other_doc)
other_doc_1 = Document.objects(_id="boe_585cb87956f09c48c999f90617e69038d3e8e0ceadca2b6030495d4126f4ab5d")
data.append(other_doc_1)
```

Output:

```
 [[Document boe_dd4a95f6ec1c41ba47239fe6fd688b8cc1232c3d25a68b76836172d99164cb82: date=2017-03-22 12:00:00, bank=Bank boe: name=Bank of England], [Document boe_585cb87956f09c48c999f90617e69038d3e8e0ceadca2b6030495d4126f4ab5d: date=2017-04-13 09:00:00, bank=Bank boe: name=Bank of England]]
```

Desired output:

```
[Document boe_dd4a95f6ec1c41ba47239fe6fd688b8cc1232c3d25a68b76836172d99164cb82: date=2017-03-22 12:00:00, bank=Bank boe: name=Bank of England, Document boe_585cb87956f09c48c999f90617e69038d3e8e0ceadca2b6030495d4126f4ab5d: date=2017-04-13 09:00:00, bank=Bank boe: name=Bank of England]
```

So I can run this:

```
for i in other_doc:
doc = str(other_doc.extracted_text)
doc_tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(doc)
print(doc_tokens)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python you could simply do `data += other_doc` instead of calling append.

So the full code would be:

```
data=[]
other_doc = Document.objects(bank="boe_dd4a95f6ec1c41ba47239fe6fd688b8cc1232c3d25a68b76836172d99164cb82")
data += other_doc
other_doc_1 = Document.objects(_id="boe_585cb87956f09c48c999f90617e69038d3e8e0ceadca2b6030495d4126f4ab5d")
data += other_doc_1
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept your answer when StackOverflow lets me!

Answer (score 1):

You could do `data += other_doc` or `data.extend(other_doc)`. Extend adds a list onto the end of the other existing list.